# Why does the zoom changes the design layout of my html page?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a project and i have faced a bug :

The design of the page ( especially the menu bar ) change on zooming

How can i prevent this ? Is there a shortage in my code ?

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Movie Guide</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        #main {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #main-menu-container {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #main-menu {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1024px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="main" style="text-align: center">
            <img src="image.jpg" width="925" height="125" />
            <div id="main-menu-container">
                <div id="main-menu">
                    <div id="menubar">
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li class="current"><a href="page1.aspx">Title 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="page2.aspx">Title 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="page3.aspx">Title 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="page4.aspx">Title 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="page5.aspx">Title 5</a></li>               
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
body {
    font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #23244e;
    color: #000;
}

#menubar {
    width: 920px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #1D1D1D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#535353, #1d1d1d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#535353, #1d1d1d);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#535353, #1d1d1d);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
}

ul#menu li {
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    display: inline;
    background: transparent;
}

    ul#menu li a {
        float: left;
        font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
        text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000;
        padding: 6px 20px 0 20px;
        background: transparent;
        border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
        -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used css for a while so my apologies if this is not the correct solution, but I believe if you put under the main menu:

```
position:absolute;
```

the menu should no longer move

Comment: I tried this but the left corner of the menu is moved to center of the page. And even if it would work correctly, the menu would be removed from the document flow, and that could cause other problems. But changing `#main-menu` `width` from 1024px to `920px` seems to work.

Comment: Oh, then just make the menubar float left, no? Or align=left ? Depending on your screen size, I think the width might not always look the same.

Comment: Better will be @Jad Chahine if you will create a Fiddle for understanding and being easy to see for us what works and what not.